# Create mixin/function for @keyframes animation that will accept parameters for changed value

Tags: sass

I want to create mixin/function in sass that will customize my @keyframes animation. It looks like I can do it using this code, but is there a better way?

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/13a4b5d4df15ca46bd484ab5758f6de0

```sass
$animation-name: 1 !global;
@mixin animate_bg($color1, $color2) {
  $animation-name: unique-id() !global;
  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
      0% {
          background-color: $color1;
      }
      100% {
          background-color: $color2;
      }
  }
  @content
}

@include animate_bg(#007efe, #cce5ff) {
  a.finished {
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-name: $animation-name;
  }
}

@include animate_bg(#aabbcc, #ffaabb) {
  b.finished {
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-name: $animation-name;
  }
}
```

Produces this css

```
@keyframes uz61m5wd4 {
  0% {
    background-color: #007efe;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #cce5ff;
  }
}
a.finished {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-name: uz61m5wd4;
}

@keyframes uz61m5wdd {
  0% {
    background-color: #aabbcc;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #ffaabb;
  }
}
b.finished {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-name: uz61m5wdd;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Shrunk the SCSS slightly by including your `.finished` class in the mixin. Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, though.

```css
// mixin:
@mixin animate_bg($color1, $color2, $class, $duration) {
  $animation-name: unique-id() !global;

  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    0% {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    100% {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }

  .#{$class}.finished {
    animation-duration: $duration;
    animation-name: $animation-name;
  }
}

// using the mixin:
@include animate_bg(#007efe, #cce5ff, a, .25s);
@include animate_bg(#aabbcc, #ffaabb, b, .25s);
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe I can even do it using only css (not sass), but "@keyframes" don't support parameters if I understood correctly. So I started trying do it with mixins, but I don't often work with sass, so I'm not sure if what I ended up with makes sense or there is an easier way